# Copy files and folders under certain size recursively

Tags: linux

How do I copy all the files and folders recursively with the same folder hierarchy. I however want to only copy files under a certain size.

Comment: The title of your question mentions directories. Do you mean to copy a directory only if the sum of the sizes of all files beneath that directory is under a particular size?

Answer (score 2):

You could utilize `rsync` with the `--max-size` option.

Answer (score 0):

Use `find -exec`

```
cd /path/to/source
find . -size -50k -type f -exec cp --parents {} /destination/ \;
```

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly, and assuming file paths don't contain newline characters:

```
find . -type f -size -10000c | pax -rw /destination/
```

Here for files smaller than 10000 bytes.

Some `find` implementations have a `-print0` predicate and some `pax` implementations a corresponding `-0` option that cause the file list to be NUL-delimited which would address the *newline* limitation mentioned above.